# Algorithm to find all legal moves in Reversi game

Tags: python, algorithm

[Reversi Game:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversi)
The image from the Reversi game:

[image]

I have my algorithm to find all legal moves in Reversi game.

Here's the code with comments:

```
"""
-1    => no disc
0/1   => player's disc
"""

for row_idx, row in enumerate(board):
    for column_idx, column in enumerate(board):
        if board[row_idx][column_idx] == -1:
            """
            Loop through square with chosen `-1` in middle
            5   5   5
            5  -1   5
            5   5   5
            """
            for i in range(-1, 2, 1):
                for j in range(-1, 2, 1):
                    """
                    Check if loop is not beyond borders
                    """
                    if row_idx + i < 0 or row_idx + 1 > (len(board) - 1) or column_idx + j < 0 or column_idx + j > (len(board) - 1):
                        continue

                    """
                    If there is a opponent disc, go straight in this direction (that way)
                    """
                    if board[row_idx + i][column_idx + j] == self.opponent_color:
                        i2, j2 = i, j
                        for _ in range(8):
                            """
                            Check if loop is not beyond borders
                            """
                            if row_idx + i + i2 < 0 or row_idx + i + i2 > (len(board) - 1) or column_idx + j + j2 < 0 or column_idx + j + j2 > (len(board) - 1):
                                continue

                            """
                            Break if the `no disc` is on `that way`
                            """
                            if board[row_idx + i + i2][column_idx + j + j2] == -1:
                                break

                            """
                            The legal move has been found, then break.
                            """
                            if board[row_idx + i + i2][column_idx + j + j2] == self.my_color:
                                legal_moves.append((row_idx, column_idx))
                                break
           
                            i2 += i
                            j2 += j
```

Is there any better way to do it? I am not sure about those nested for loops.

Thanks for any help or any hint!

Comment: Are you sure this algorithm works? Why is there a random 7 in the border check? Why is `column_idx + j` always expected to be 0 on every iteration and how do you get around the code crashing with `i2` and `j2` not being defined if opponent stone is not found on the first iteration?

Comment: (1) There is 8x8 board, the last one is 7th index in array. (2)(3) I am sorry, bad indentation in the code, not mine on local, but here on CodeReview. I'll fix it, give me one minute.

Comment: @LevM. I have fixed indentation in my code.

Comment: It makes more sense now, but there is still this condition in the outer loop: `column_idx + j < 0 or column_idx + j > 0` I am guessing it needs 7 in the end instead of 0, just like the rows condition. I would recommend that instead of using hardcoded board size you use `len()` function on your actual board this will make the code clearer and more versatile. You already enumerate based on board size anyway.

Comment: I really think you should thoroughly describe what your program does since not everyone knows reversi

Comment: @LevM. Thanks, I have edited my code.

Comment: @AryanParekh [Reversi link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversi) I have added the image from the game as well.

Comment: Without having `board`, how are we supposed to try your code or our suggestions? Should have an input+output example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Iteration

This:

```
for row_idx, row in enumerate(board):
    for column_idx, column in enumerate(board):
        if board[row_idx][column_idx] == -1:
```

is effectively incorrect. Is your board in row-major or column-major order? Whichever is true, you cannot iterate over the outer index of the board and get *both* a row and a column. What you likely meant instead is:

```
for row_idx, row in enumerate(board):
    for column_idx, cell in enumerate(row):
        if cell == -1:
```

Another problematic iteration is this:

```
i2, j2 = i, j
for _ in range(8):
    # ...
    i2 += i
    j2 += j
```

should simply be

```
for delta in range(1, 8):
    # ... use i*delta instead of i2
    # ... use j*delta instead of j2
```

### Combined range checking

```
if row_idx + i < 0 or row_idx + 1 > (len(board) - 1) or column_idx + j < 0 or column_idx + j > (len(board) - 1):
```

should be

```
if not (0 <= row_idx + i < len(board)) or not (0 <= column_idx < len(board)):
```

Comment: (1) Oh, my fault, thanks. (3) Interesting, thanks for it. (2) I think this is not what I mean. I need to go in direction the opponent disc is. The point is, the direction could be <-1; 1>.

Comment: @JohnDoe I had that wrong on the first pass; you're incrementing by `i` and `j` respectively so you can just multiply by delta instead. The alternative is to `zip` two ranges, which is a little uglier.

Comment: You are right, I get it know, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

Avoid magic numbers like -1,0,1. Instead, define constants for the values in the squares:

```
EMPTY = -1
WHITE =  0
BLACK =  1
```

One technique for implementing a grid or board like this is to add an extra row on the right and an extra column on the bottom filled with an "out of bounds" marker.  For example, your code uses -1 for empty spaces and 0/1 for the pieces.  You could use -2 for the out-of-bounds squares.  An initial reversi board might look like this.

```
board = [
    #  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8  OoB
    [ -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -2 ],  # 1
    [ -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -2 ],  # 2
    [ -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -2 ],  # 3
    [ -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -2 ],  # 4
    [ -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -2 ],  # 5
    [ -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -2 ],  # 6
    [ -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -2 ],  # 7
    [ -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -2 ],  # 8
    [ -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2 ]   # OoB
    ]
```

Doing this simplifies testing adjacent indexes to see if they are in bounds:

```
if row_idx + i < 0 or row_idx + 1 > (len(board) - 1) or column_idx + j < 0 or column_idx + j > (len(board) - 1):
    continue
```

becomes:

```
OUT_OF_BOUNDS = -2

if board[row_idx + i][col_idx + j] == OUT_OF_BOUNDS:
    continue
```

or, just skip that test because the square won't pass the next test anyway (if the square has opponent's color).

Also, you can reduce the depth of nesting by changing the loops.  Instead of:
SIZE = 8

```
for row_idx range(HEIGHT):
    for column_idx in range(WIDTH):
        ...
```

use:

```
from itertools import product

for row_idx, col_idx in product(range(HEIGHT), range(WIDTH)):
    ...
```

And instead of:

```
for i in range(-1, 2, 1):
    for j in range(-1, 2, 1):
        ...
```

use:

```
for i,j in ((-1,-1), (-1,0), (-1, 1),
            ( 0,-1),         ( 0, 1),
            ( 1,-1), ( 1,0), ( 1, 1)):
    ...
```

Which also skips the case of i = j = 0.

Also, i, j, i2, and j2 are not very descriptive. It would be easy to miss a mistake like `board[row_idx + j]`.  Use something like `row_step` or `dr` (delta_row).